# How do I show a PDF's table of contents in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Chrome seems to use it's own PDF reader which is fairly nice, but is there any way to display the table of contents in it?  Some PDFs simply lack pages for a traditional index and simply use the PDF TOC feature.

Related: can it show me the page number and allow me to enter one to go to?

Comment: After browsing the Google Chrome Help Forum, http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5809f4752164157a&hl=en, it seems like it's not integrated just yet. Might just have to download the file locally and use your preferred pdf reader for now.

Comment: The reason I don't use the integrated reader in Chrome, hopefully it will be included in some future version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You now can! [Added in version 87](https://www.dignited.com/72975/chromes-updated-pdf-viewer-now-includes-a-side-panel-and-table-of-contents/) around November 2020, it's in the bookmark button.

[image: Screenshot of the Chrome PDF viewer with arrow pointing at bookmark button in the top right.]

Answer (score 2):

It certainly seems that the answer is "you can't do that yet". Might I suggest reporting an issue about it, and telling us the URL?

Comment: I guess this is the answer, but what are you talking about with a URL?  If you want to know more about PDF TOCs you could probably look at some standards document, but as an end user, ignorance is bliss.

Comment: @Nick: I meant that you should tell us, in a comment, the URL for any issue you file against Chrome regarding this omission. I certainly know where to look if I want to find out more information about how precisely these handy ToC/outline/bookmark trees are represented in a PDF file; I have the relevant PDF open as I write this (but for largely unrelated reasons).

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110020